# Document Library Filter

Tags: 2013, document-library, filter, view

This may seem like a simple question, but I have spent hours trying to get this function to work properly.  I have two data columns in a document library with a view titled "today".  The idea is as follows: if I were to enter in a meeting time from 11/25/2013 to 11/29/2013 I would like for that meeting to remain in the today web part window until 11/30/2013.  Listed below is what I placed into the filter thus far, however, it only shows today for today only.  How would I show the meeting until after the meeting date is over?  Thank you for your help.

**View Filter:** 
Start Date 
is equal to 
[Today]

or

End Date is equal to [Today]+30

****UPDATE****
Sorry if I wasn't clear above.  I have a web part that shows [Today].  However, if I have a meeting that lasts for more than one day I do not want the meeting to disappear from the web part.  The only time I want the web part to disappear is the day after the meeting ends.  View the image below.  The items in the red box will start present in the web part created until the end date is passed.  Thanks again!

[image]

***UPDATE (12/11/2013)***: 
After more testing.  The following filter view has gotten me close to a resolution.

Start Date is greater than or equal to [Today]

And

End Date is less than or equal to [Today]

Or

End Date is greater than or equal to [Today]

The last issue I am experiencing is it returns all entries that have a start date greater than [Today].  Can anyone see what I am missing?  Maybe I need to walk away and come back. :)

**UPDATE (12/16/2013)**
To add a little bit of clarity, please view the image below.
[image]
Today's date is 12/16/2013.  Looking at the image above, Meeting 1, Meeting 2, Meeting 4, and Meeting 5 should be the only meetings that appear in the web part. On tomorrow, 12/17/2013, the Meeting 1 should disappear, because the 16th has passed.  Meeting 2, Meeting 4 and Meeting 5 will remain, because the end date is greater than Today's date.  If a meeting is added for 12/25/2013 to 01/02/2014.  The meeting will appear in the web part until 12/25/2013 and will not disappear until 01/02/2014. Sorry for the confusion. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Could you have  field called "Current meeting?" with the default being No. A workflow runs on item creation, waits until the meting starts, changes "Current meeting?" to Yes, waits until the meeting end, changes "Current meeting?" to No. Your filtered view could just show meetings where "Current meeting?" is Yes. This is assuming that once a meeting is tnetered the dates won't change

Comment: That is great idea.  However, for this task I want to simply show who is in the meeting and/or teleworking. So after they enter in their time it will show those particular dates for only that designated time period. Thanks for your help, Enilorac. Appreciate it.

Comment: I think you need to add more information to your quesion to make it clear what you want showing, maybe with an example

Comment: Hi Enilorac.  I updated the post.  Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand your requirements correctly, I would do the following:

Start Date is greater than or equal to [Today]

and

End Date is less than or equal to [Today]

Comment: Hi BlueBird.  Thank you for your response.  Sorry if I wasn't clear earlier.  I updated my questions above with more information. Once you read the update, can you still help me? Thanks!

Comment: seems like the above would still work...no?

Comment: Thanks, BlueBird.  Sorry, that didn't work.  I will keep trying but I have tested the filter.